# KivyMD: Contents of Screen overlap with Toolbar

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm writing a simple app in KivyMD. According to the kivy documentation my .kv structure with MDNavigationDrawer and MDToolbar is right and everything works fine as long as the screens are empty. When I add content to them, the content instead of being under the Toolbar is above it. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Test"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"
                ScrollView:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        Button:
                            text: "Hello"
                        Button:
                            text: "I wish"
                        Button:
                            text: "I could"
                        Button:
                            text: "Finally get"
                        Button:
                            text: "This to work"


            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Output of the following code:
[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Screen` class is a `RelativeLayout`, so you must position its children as you would any `RelativeLayout`. Every child of the `Screen` gets the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)` and the default `pos` of `(0,0)`, so you must adjust it if that is not what you want. In your case, the `NavigationLayout` will completely cover the `Screen` based on those default values. You can fix that by just adding a `size_hint_y`, like this:

```
NavigationLayout:
    x: toolbar.height
    size_hint_y: 1.0 - toolbar.height/root.height
```

This sets the size of the `NavigationLayout` so that it just meets the bottom of the `MDToolbar` instead of overlpping it.

Answer (score 1):

A most elegant solution is to insert the `MDToolbar` and `NavigationLayout` into a `BoxLayout` with `orientation: "vertical"` so the NavigationLayout start at the bottom of the Toolbar, without calculating the relative position.

```
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:

        MDNavigationLayout:
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the order of appearance that is the problem:
If the screen has other widgets such as cards and Layouts, all of these must appear first.

i.e. put the Navigation Layout and the respective screen manager at the bottom.

What comes last appears on top of everything else.

That worked for me.